# Incorrect syntax near 'Yeri'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, forms

I need help.

This is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog=CallCenterDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    conn.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Rehber1 (id,Birimi,Görev Yeri,Adi Soyadi,Merkez Santral-1,Merkez Santral-2,Merkez Santral-3,Merkez Santral-4,Merkez Santral-5,Merkez Santral-6,Sekreter Dahili-1,Sekreter Dahili-2,Sekreter Direkt-1,Sekreter Direkt-2,Dect,Fax,Cep,Kisa Kod,Ev,Ozel Makam Numaralari,Telsiz Kod,Uydu Thuraya,Uydu Fax No,Uydu Data No,Uydu G Star,Bagli Oldugu Genel Sekr Yard,Bagli Oldugu Müdürlük, Zabita,Ozel Kalem Md,Ozel Kalem Md Cep,Yangin Tel,Muhabere Tel,Kanal,Musteri Hizmetleri,Randevu  Adres,Web Adres,Aciklama) VALUES(@c1,@c2,@c3,@c4,@c5,@c6,@c7,@c8,@c9,@c10,@c11,@c12,@c13,@c14,@c15,,@c16,@c17,@c18,@c19,@c20,@c21,@c22,@c23,@c24,@c25,@c26,@c27,@c28,@c29,@c30,@c31,@c32,@c33,@c34,@c35,@c36,@c37,@c38)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C3", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C4", row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C5", row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C6", row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C7", row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C8", row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C9", row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C10", row.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C11", row.Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C12", row.Cells[11].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C13", row.Cells[12].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C14", row.Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C15", row.Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C16", row.Cells[15].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C17", row.Cells[16].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C18", row.Cells[17].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C19", row.Cells[18].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C20", row.Cells[19].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C21", row.Cells[20].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C22", row.Cells[21].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C23", row.Cells[22].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C24", row.Cells[23].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C25", row.Cells[24].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C26", row.Cells[25].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C27", row.Cells[26].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C28", row.Cells[27].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C29", row.Cells[28].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C30", row.Cells[29].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C31", row.Cells[30].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C32", row.Cells[31].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C33", row.Cells[32].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C34", row.Cells[33].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C35", row.Cells[34].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C36", row.Cells[35].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C37", row.Cells[36].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C38", row.Cells[37].Value.ToString());

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'Yeri'

but code does not contain "yeri".

Comment: Code contain Yeri: `INSERT INTO Rehber1 (id,Birimi,Görev Yeri,`...

Comment: Field names can't contain spaces unless you surround them with brackets (I assume this is for SQL server).

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` to escape since your column name contains space like

```
INSERT INTO Rehber1 (id,Birimi,[Görev Yeri]...
```